# Valence and Release Conditions?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Is there a way to add a release condition to a content item using Valence? Alternatively is there a way to programmatically copy an individual content item somehow from one course offering to another such that it keeps its release conditions?

Comment: Sadly I don't believe there is a way to add release conditions via the APIs at the moment. Copying the content with an existing release condition is an interesting idea; I'll check and get back to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this functionality isn't available in the Valence APIs yet. Copying content won't reliably copy the release conditions either.